Tkinter treeview color not changing
when I configure the style for the tkinter treeview it works for the headings but fails for the rows, the size of the rows changes but the background and the fore ground donot change.
Here is the code:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox  # Add this line to import the messagebox module
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import pymysql
import datetime

________________ rest of the code _____________________

def enrollinfo():
    subrootlvl2prev.destroy()
        #________________________________________________________________rightframe
    rightframe = Frame(subrootlvl1, bg='white', bd=2, relief='groove')
    rightframe.place(x=380, y=80, width=890, height=760)
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('Treeview.Heading',font=('Ariel', 18, 'bold'),foreground='dark slate blue')
    style.configure('Treeview', font=('Ariel', 11, 'bold'), foreground='white', background='black')
    scroll_x = Scrollbar(rightframe, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scroll_y = Scrollbar(rightframe, orient=VERTICAL)
    #__________________________________treeview
    tabletree = ttk.Treeview(rightframe, columns=('CNIC STD', 'Student Name', 'Father Name', 'Course', 'Duration', 'Net Fee','Instructor Name'), xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
    for col in tabletree['columns']:
        tabletree.heading(col, text=col)
    tabletree.column('CNIC STD', width=200)
    tabletree.column('Student Name', width=180)
    tabletree.column('Father Name', width=200)
    tabletree.column('Course', width=200)
    tabletree.column('Duration', width=120)
    tabletree.column('Net Fee', width=100)
    tabletree.column('Instructor Name', width=200)



    # to not display empty column
    tabletree['show'] = 'headings'
    scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    scroll_x.config(command=tabletree.xview)
    scroll_y.config(command=tabletree.yview)
    tabletree.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


are there any problems with the code? I didnot find anyother syntax on the internet

Try another theme as not all stylings are supported for certain themes.

not working I have tried almost all the themes

Try setting fieldbackground='black' as well in style.configure('Treeview', ...).
